# API for document language translation

Tags: api, translation, google-translate

I searched for an API which takes a document as an input and translates that document into a specified language but I'm unable able to find such an API.

I know Google provides an API to translate text but here I need to translate a whole document and return it translated. Please let me know if any API like this is available.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the Pairaphrase [translation API](https://www.pairaphrase.com/how-it-works/api-for-developers). 
It will translate documents (and other files) from one language into another.

Just note that Pairaphrase is really meant to be used as a translation productivity tool for businesses. It won't give you perfect translation.

Instead, it facilitates secure, high-quality translation by doing the following.

- It uses machine translation and translation memory to translate your files quickly (as a 1st draft).
- Then, it's up to the user to share (using the "share" feature inside Pairaphrase) the translated files with bilingual users inside and/or outside their organizations to edit the translations within Pairaphrase.
- When this is done correctly, Pairaphrase learns human-translated words and phrases so that you never need to translate the same phrases or sentences twice.
- All translation data is encrypted and two-factor authentication is available to provide data security.

They have a [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87LJtnBTNNo) that you can check out. This will give you a feel for the functionality and if this translation API is right for you.

Comment: its quite expensive. 125$ for only 25k words